# Symfony method is not getting called in jquery on submit action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, symfony

I am trying to call jquery ajax function on submit button of a form. My form is in the form of twig and I have mentioned no action as I want to do a ajax call.

```
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" value="" />

      <label for="email">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" value="" />

      <input type="submit" name="action" id="login" value="login" />
```

My js looks like this:

```
     $("#login").click(function(event) {
        var posting = $.post(http://domain-name/api/login, $('#mainform').serialize(), function(data,status) {
        if(status == 'success'){
```

When I click on submit button, it does not redirect to this url. Instead it takes relative url and tries to find out the path for app->post('/login') which is not defined.

I am not getting why it is not calling the js functions.

Comment: If u've enclosed your code within form tag: Try changing `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: need more code, what is "url"? can you post the entire form?

Comment: Url is a global url - an api call

Comment: Can you add the routing? And are the two pages on the same domain? If they're not on the same domain you cannot do an AJAX call without using JSON-P!

Comment: They are in the same domain. Problem is the request is getting served by php and it is not going through a normal js path

Comment: Could you add your routing to the question (the portion relevant to the question)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify submit button. Instead put:

```
<input type="button" name="action" id="login" value="login" />
```

Or use the method preventDefault
And do not save to a variable the post function, im not a js expert, but it looks like you are saving on it a function... And use double quotes on URL

```
$("#login").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://domain-name/api/login", $('#mainform').serialize(), function); 
}
```